# What to order at a Japanese restaurant?

Tags: japanese-cuisine

We would be visiting a Japanese restaurant this weekend. However we are completely clueless what should we order this being our first time. Could you suggest something for beginners?  Normally we prefer Indian cuisine and sometimes Chinese as well. To change our monotonous eating habits we decided to visit this place. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most restaurants, especially if they offer a particular cuisine, will welcome you with open arms if you simply admit that this is your first time for trying this particular food.

There are many kinds of Japanese restaurants. It is not possible to recommend what to order, because depending on the type of restaurant they may not have it on the menu.

But if you explain to the wait staff that you do not have any previous experience with this establishment and would like some advice on what might be a good choice, I'm sure that any restaurant will be happy to make recommendations. They should ask you if you prefer meat or fish or if you like your food spicy or mild. Then they should point out suitable items on the menu for you to consider.